# How can I change the JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

```
// Update the radius when the user makes a selection.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('radius'),
    'change', function() {
       var meters = parseInt(this.value, 10);
       layer.setOptions({
         query: {
           select: locationColumn,
           from: tableId,
           where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(Latitude, ' +
               'CIRCLE(LATLNG(53.337638, -6.266971), ' + meters + '))'
          }
       });
       circle.setRadius(meters);
       //alert(position);
       //circle.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position));
});
```

I want to change the  (53.337638, -6.266971) to be a varible 'position', position has the same value type with (x,y), but it doesn't work with 
where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(Latitude, ' +
                      'CIRCLE(LATLNG('+position+'), ' + meters + '))'
How can I modify the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short solution is:

```
var position = [53.337638, -6.266971];
// irrelenant query code skipped
... + 'CIRCLE(LATLNG('+position[0]+','+position[1]+'), ' ...
```

A longer (but better semantically) solution would be to define an object with two properties,
then overload its toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the two properties of `position` individually, like this:

```
LATLNG(position.x, position.y)
```